# Multiple part of a sum

Tags: excel

I am trying to add sales from 5 days, each day a new column. I want to then take the first $50,000 and multiply by a percent, then 50-70k and multiply by another percent. Is this possible and what formula would I use?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a photo of your excel set up please. Show the expected outputs as well so we have something to validate against

Comment: I don't really have much to go by, I am prepping a sheet for next year. Plus its really hard to explain! I will keep trying to figure out thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53820472/edit) with a screen cap of what you do have. Sound like all you need are nested `IF`s: `=IF(A1<50000,A1*0.1,IF(A1<70000,5000+(A1-50000)*0.15,IF(A1<90000,1,8000+(A1-70000)*0.2)))`

Comment: I added the simple worksheet I have, each day will be different numbers  I want to be able to type in so if I make 20k each day half of day 3 would go to the first equation to the right, then anything up to 70k will go to 2nd equation to right.

Comment: So can you show us what the answer would be?

Comment: Sorry the mathamatical answer so we have a bench mark for the formula to ensure correct output.

Comment: $50,000 x .35 = $17,500.00, after that 50k anything up to 70k would be multiplied by .40 (so it depends on sales), then after 70k anything up to 100k would be multiplied by .50. (once again depends on sales.

Comment: do you want the final value in one cell, multiple, can we use a helper column?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if it's not something you want. Assume you're calculating some sort of commission on the basis of sales at progressive rates: 35% on the first $50,000,  40% on the next $20,000 and 50% on the remaining.

Mathematically, the answer to your example should be $40,500 and here's the breakdown:

[image]

This Excel formula gives the expected amount, referencing cell 'M2' as the total sales:

```
=IF(M2<=50000,M2*0.35,IF(M2<=70000,17500+(M2-50000)*0.4,17500+8000+(M2-70000)*0.5))
```

The pseudocode to help you understand the formula more easily:

```
If totalSale <= $50,000, set commission = totalSale x 0.35 
Else if totalSale <=70000, set commission = 17500 + (totalSale - 50000) x 0.40 
Else set commission = 17500 + 8000 + (totalSale - 70000) x 0.50
```

You may wish to use more nested-if if there are more progressive rates. Check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-%E2%80%93-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8) out. Good luck!